# generate group (family) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following type of data:

```
Person <- c("A",  "B", "C",  "D",  "E",  "E",  "F",  "G", "H", "I")
MOM <- c(   NA,   NA,   NA,  "A",  "A",   NA,  "A",  "B", "C", NA)
DAD <- c(   NA,   NA,   NA,  "B",  "B",   NA,  "E",  "A", "B", NA)
Xv <- 1:10
myd <- data.frame (Person, MOM, DAD, Xv, stringsAsFactors=F)
myd 
       Person  MOM  DAD Xv
1       A <NA> <NA>  1
2       B <NA> <NA>  2
3       C <NA> <NA>  3
4       D    A    B  4
5       E    A    B  5
6       E <NA> <NA>  6
7       F    A    E  7
8       G    B    A  8
9       H    C    B  9
10      I <NA> <NA> 10
```

This data include Person and their Mom and Dad columns. I would like to create family group for this data. NA is information missing. A family is defined that has common MOM and DAD. Founders are those that have both NA, family = 0.

Here is what I could figure out, which is imperfect for me:

```
fun <- function(i) {
  i1 <- if (is.na(myd[i, 2])) i else match(myd[i, 2], myd[1:i, 2])
  i2 <- if (is.na(myd[i, 3])) i else match(myd[i, 3], myd[1:i, 3])
  min(i1, i2)
}
myd$family <- as.numeric(factor(sapply(1:nrow(myd), fun)))
  Person  MOM  DAD Xv family
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      1
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      2
3       C <NA> <NA>  3      3
4       D    A    B  4      4
5       E    A    B  5      4
6       E <NA> <NA>  6      5
7       F    A    E  7      4
8       G    B    A  8      6
9       H    C    B  9      4
10      I <NA> <NA> 10      7
```

The above function is imperfect in the sense:
The family data do not include data of their parents, for example family 4 should include 
data for A and B. Thus complete family would look like:

```
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      1
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      2
4       D    A    B  4      4
5       E    A    B  5      4
```

Another thing (at least for my purpose is), Being DAD = A and MOM = B is same as DAD = B, and MOM = A. Thus the family 4 and 6 are product of same A and B parents, so should be 
same.

```
4       D    A    B  4      4
5       E    A    B  5      4
8       G    B    A  8      6
```

Thus expected output is:

```
Person  MOM  DAD Xv     family
# founders 
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      0
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      0
3       C <NA> <NA>  3      0
10      I <NA> <NA> 10      0
6       E <NA> <NA>  6      0
# Family 1
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      1
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      1
4       D    A    B  4      1
5       E    A    B  5      1
8       G    B    A  8      1
# Family 2
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      2
6       E <NA> <NA>  6      2
7       F    A    E  7      2
# Family 3
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      3
3       C <NA> <NA>  3      3
9       H    C    B  9      3
```

**Edits:**

It is pity (good !) in human genetics we need to work on similar variables - family, trio, mom (parent1, mother, female), father (dad, parent2, male), individual / subject etc. This makes everything similar and issue are similar.

```
  Family vs Trio 
  1 Nuclear family 
  A  x   B
      |
   C   D  E

  Trio -> 3 trios  
  A x B      A x B       A x B
     |         |            |
     C          D           E
```

**Edits from the questioner:** I you agree with the comments below as homework, please do not anwer the question for sometime (the time you think good enough that homework submission time has passed). If I get answer I will post it later (in 3 months or so).

**Edits**

**Founders definition** - those who have both parents unknown whether they are any sons / daughters, so they have  in both MOM and DAD columns. These are considered family 0 as they are part of other families but the list is not real family.

```
 Person  MOM  DAD Xv     family
    1       A <NA> <NA>  1      0
    2       B <NA> <NA>  2      0
    3       C <NA> <NA>  3      0
    10      I <NA> <NA> 10      0
    6       E <NA> <NA>  6      0
```

** Family definition *** A family consists of parents (MOM and DAD)  and all son and daughters. If Person DAD and MOM  matches with Another Person DAD and MOM, they should be considered a family. For example, D and E person in the following list has MOM = A and DAD = B, these two individuals together with D and E consists of a family. Now we need to recycle data for their parents (A and B ) from the founders list (family 0).

```
 # Family 1
        Person  MOM  DAD     Xv     family
    1       A <NA> <NA>  1      1
    2       B <NA> <NA>  2      1
    4       D    A    B  4      1
    5       E    A    B  5      1
```

Also in contrary to human situation here a individual can be MOM or DAD (can switch sex), so progeny produced by A (MOM) and B (DAD) are same as pro-genies developed by B (MOM) and A(DAD), thus we need to add the following to individual to family 1 list.

```
       Person  MOM   DAD     Xv     family
   8       G       B    A       8      1
```

Thus complete list for family 1 becomes:

```
     Person  MOM   DAD Xv     family
1       A <NA> <NA>  1      1
2       B <NA> <NA>  2      1
4       D    A    B  4      1
5       E    A    B  5      1
8       G    B    A  8      1
```

The family 1 can be diagrammatically sketched as:

```
            MOM   x   DAD             MOM   x   DAD
              A  |   B        or       B  |     A 
            -----------------          ------
           |                 |           |
           D                 E           G
```

**Here is partial solution:**

```
myd1 <- data.frame(myd$DAD, myd$MOM) 
myd$family<-as.factor(apply(myd1,1,function(x){paste(x[order(x)],collapse='-')}))
   Person  MOM  DAD Xv family
1       A <NA> <NA>  1  NA-NA
2       B <NA> <NA>  2  NA-NA
3       C <NA> <NA>  3  NA-NA
4       D    A    B  4    A-B
5       E    A    B  5    A-B
6       E <NA> <NA>  6  NA-NA
7       F    A    E  7    A-E
8       G    B    A  8    A-B
9       H    C    B  9    B-C
10      I <NA> <NA> 10  NA-NA
```

It does not give family number rather family of A and B. NA-NA is founders and it orders before collapse so the A-B becomes B-A.

**What is issue remaining** is that A-B family needs data from Person A and B recycled (although they are in family NA-NA group) .

```
  Person  MOM  DAD Xv family
1       A <NA> <NA>  1  NA-NA
2       B <NA> <NA>  2  NA-NA
4       D    A    B  4    A-B
5       E    A    B  5    A-B
```

Comment: How is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/11513895/602276 ?

Comment: @Andrie -- because it is being asked by a different person? Homework?

Comment: @mrdwab Ah, that would make sense, wouldn't it? Nothing interesting here. I'm moving on.

Comment: @Andrie The question is different although the variables are quite similar - mom dad etc that human people need to work with ...It need to generate family rather trio...

Comment: @mrdwab  This is not homework....I argue everybody not to answer this question for some time if you think so and homework time is lapse ....so that if I have answer I will post it for good of everybody

Comment: Even if it's not homework, it is poorly constructed. Use person identifiers that are more like your real data. The ambiguities are well illustrated by looking at the differences between your suggested output and what you get with my incorrect solution.

Comment: @DWin thanks, I know something can not be mother or father in humans, but I was willing to make a general solution and that is possible to make something mother at times and father another times while making artificial mating / crosses in hermanphrodites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've figured this out yet, but here is one solution.

First, your data:

```
# Your data
myd <- data.frame(Person = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                             "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
                  MOM = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, "A", "B", "C", NA),
                  DAD = c(NA, NA, NA, "B", "B", NA, "E", "A", "B", NA),
                  Xv = 1:10, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Second, we identify the families by merging together columns 2 and 3 from your original data. We will use this to `split` your `data.frame` into a list.

```
# Identifying the families
fam = apply(myd[2:3], 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse=" "))
```

Third, we split the `data.frame` into a list. In this case, we end up with a list of four `data.frame`s: one for the founders, and one for each family.

```
# Splitting the data by founders and families
temp_1 = split(myd, fam)
names(temp_1)[1] = "Founders"
```

Fourth, we do some simple matching and subsetting to identify which founders belong to which families.

```
# Identify which families the founders belong to
temp_2 = lapply(1:length(temp_1),
                function(x) temp_1[[1]][which(temp_1[[1]]$Person %in% 
                  unique(unlist(temp_1[[x]][,c(2,3)], use.names=FALSE))),])
```

And, finally, we `rbind` this data together.

```
# "Merging" (with rbind) founders and their families
OUT = lapply(1:length(temp_1), function(x) rbind(temp_2[[x]], temp_1[[x]]))
names(OUT) = names(temp_1)
```

This is the output:

```
OUT
# $Founders
#    Person  MOM  DAD Xv
# 1       A <NA> <NA>  1
# 2       B <NA> <NA>  2
# 3       C <NA> <NA>  3
# 6       E <NA> <NA>  6
# 10      I <NA> <NA> 10
# 
# $`A B`
#   Person  MOM  DAD Xv
# 1      A <NA> <NA>  1
# 2      B <NA> <NA>  2
# 4      D    A    B  4
# 5      E    A    B  5
# 8      G    B    A  8
# 
# $`A E`
#   Person  MOM  DAD Xv
# 1      A <NA> <NA>  1
# 6      E <NA> <NA>  6
# 7      F    A    E  7
# 
# $`B C`
#   Person  MOM  DAD Xv
# 2      B <NA> <NA>  2
# 3      C <NA> <NA>  3
# 9      H    C    B  9
```

### Update: data.frame output

If you prefer a `data.frame` to a `list`, you can do the following *after* completing the previous steps:

```
OUT = do.call("rbind", 
              lapply(1:length(OUT), 
                     function(x) cbind(OUT[[x]], fam = names(OUT[x]))))
OUT
#    Person  MOM  DAD Xv      fam
# 1       A <NA> <NA>  1 Founders
# 2       B <NA> <NA>  2 Founders
# 3       C <NA> <NA>  3 Founders
# 6       E <NA> <NA>  6 Founders
# 10      I <NA> <NA> 10 Founders
# 11      A <NA> <NA>  1      A B
# 21      B <NA> <NA>  2      A B
# 4       D    A    B  4      A B
# 5       E    A    B  5      A B
# 8       G    B    A  8      A B
# 12      A <NA> <NA>  1      A E
# 61      E <NA> <NA>  6      A E
# 7       F    A    E  7      A E
# 22      B <NA> <NA>  2      B C
# 31      C <NA> <NA>  3      B C
# 9       H    C    B  9      B C
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a character vector that is the same for each "family" then using the `interaction` function would be more compact. Something along these lines:

```
myd$fam <- with( myd, as.character( interaction(MOM,DAD)))
myd$fam[ is.na(myd$fam) ] <- 0
```

If you want numbers (which seems unwise, but that is how you offered your request) then instead of `as.character`, use `as.numeric`

```
myd$fam <- with( myd, as.numeric( interaction(MOM,DAD)))
myd$fam[ is.na(myd$fam) ] <- 0
```

I never figured out how you could have "A" represent both a MOM and a DAD. You may need to work on explaining how your understand that aspect of human genetics. For the splitting by family use `split`

```
> split(myd, myd$fam)
$`0`
   Person  MOM  DAD Xv fam
1       A <NA> <NA>  1   0
2       B <NA> <NA>  2   0
3       C <NA> <NA>  3   0
6       E <NA> <NA>  6   0
10      I <NA> <NA> 10   0

$`2`
  Person MOM DAD Xv fam
8      G   B   A  8   2

$`4`
  Person MOM DAD Xv fam
4      D   A   B  4   4
5      E   A   B  5   4

$`6`
  Person MOM DAD Xv fam
9      H   C   B  9   6

$`7`
  Person MOM DAD Xv fam
7      F   A   E  7   7
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, the only thing that is remaining in the solution that MOM and DAD being represented in their families, for example fam 2 with person G should have data from B and A (although it is in founders family 0), just repeated.

Comment: You need to do a better job of articulating the "founders" operational definition. If that definition is dependent on the sequence of data as it comes across in lines, then you _also_ need to say so. I'm not willing to put in any more effort until there is a more comprehensible representation of the male/female/hemaphrodite identified. If this is really something regarding aspecies that has such genteic behavior then you need to describe the domain more fully.

Comment: I have tried to explain in length, please see my recent edits. I have got a partial solution (see in edits), thanks